# IE7 IE8 layout broken if advanced aggregation is enabled

Tags: 7, theming, performance, css-js-aggregation

When I install & enable [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg), my site layout breaks in IE7 and IE8.

How could that happen? Is there CSS3 in the compiled/compressed CSS? What should I do?

Comment: What theme / basetheme are you using?

Comment: Have you tried the latest dev? If yes and this is still happening please [open an issue](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/advagg) for advagg :)

Comment: @MPD > basetheme : Omega

Comment: I installed the latest version (7.x-2.0-alpha1+14-dev) maybe onpening an issue is the quickest way, if anyone had axperienced this. Thanks